# NestJS Dependency Resolution Issue in Modular Architecture

Tags: typescript, dependency-injection, module, nestjs, typescript-typings

i am a beginner with Nest.js.

I am currently facing a dependency resolution issue in a NestJS application, and I'm hoping to get some help resolving it.

I'm using NestJS with a modular architecture, where different modules are imported into each other. In a simple scenario where one module imports just one other module, everything works fine. For example, I have a Fs_So_Module that imports FailureSoModule, and I can use services from the latter without any issues.

Fs_So_Module calling FailureSoModule:

```
@Module({
  imports: [TypeOrmModule.forFeature([Fs_So]), FailureSoModule],
  controllers: [Fs_So_Controller],
  providers: [Fs_SoService],
  exports: [Fs_SoService],
})
export class Fs_So_Module {}
```

So i can use the service FailureSoService inside my Fs_SoService :

```
@Injectable()
export class Fs_SoService {
  constructor(
    @InjectRepository(Fs_So)
    private fs_SoRepository: Repository<Fs_So>,
    private failure_So_Service: FailureSoService,
  ) {}
```

However, when I have a more complex structure where one module imports a module using an other module, I encounter dependency resolution difficulties. Here's an example of the code:

i add a module in the previous exemple, now SubOrderModule is calling Fs_So_Module (remaining Fs_So_Module is using  FailureSoModule), so following Nest principle i should have:

```
@Module({
  imports: [
    TypeOrmModule.forFeature([Sub_Order]),
    SetupSoModule,
    ImageSoModule,
    Fs_So_Module,
  ],
  controllers: [SubOrderController],
  providers: [SubOrderService],
  exports: [SubOrderService],
})
export class SubOrderModule {}
```

and in the SubOrderService i am calling the service:

```
@Injectable()
export class SubOrderService {
  constructor(
    @InjectRepository(Sub_Order)
    private subOrderRepository: Repository<Sub_Order>,
    private readonly setupSoService: SetupSoService,
    private readonly imageSoService: ImageSoService,
    private readonly fs_So_Service: Fs_SoService,
  ) {}
```

In this case, even though I'm correctly importing the necessary modules and declaring the services, NestJS fails to resolve the dependency to Fs_SoService. I receive the following error:

[Nest] 13844 - 13/03/2024, 10:46:04 ERROR [ExceptionHandler] Nest can't resolve dependencies of the SubOrderService (Sub_OrderRepository, SetupSoService, ImageSoService, ?). Please make sure that the argument Fs_SoService at index [3] is available in the SubOrderModule context.

The solution i find is:

```
@Module({
  imports: [
    TypeOrmModule.forFeature([Sub_Order, Fs_So, Failure_so]),
    SetupSoModule,
    ImageSoModule,
    Fs_So_Module,
    FailureSoModule,
  ],
  controllers: [SubOrderController],
  providers: [SubOrderService, Fs_SoService, FailureSoService],
  exports: [SubOrderService],
})
export class SubOrderModule {}
```

but i dont understand it, why i should call the module, the TypeOrmModule, and the service  too?

Notice, that everything ( seems to be ) is find with the import module in my app.module

I've tried checking if SubOrderModule is properly defined as a valid NestJS module, and if Fs_SoService is correctly imported and declared in the context of SubOrderModule, but I can't seem to find the source of the problem.

Do you have any suggestions on how to resolve this dependency resolution issue in a NestJS modular architecture? Thank you in advance for your assistance.

you can find the repo here:
[text](https://github.com/Matthieudegny/dashboard_back)

Best regards,

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't need to re-declare the `Fa_SoService` in the `SubOrderModule`, but instead in the `Fa_SoModule` the `Fa_SoService` should be in both the `providers` and the `exports` array, to allow other modules (like the `SubOrderModule`) to make use of the providers that the module exports. If you add the `Fa_SoService` to the `exports` array of the `Fa_SoModule` then you should be able to remove the `Fa_SoService` from the `providers` array of the `SubOrderModule`, along with the related entities in the `TypeOrmModule.forFeature()` array

Comment: Thank you for your response,
i am not sure to understand you, because in the code :
````
@Module({
  imports: [TypeOrmModule.forFeature([Fs_So]), FailureSoModule],
  controllers: [Fs_So_Controller],
  providers: [Fs_SoService],
  exports: [Fs_SoService],
})
export class Fs_So_Module {}
```
Fs_SoService is already in the provider and the export of the Fs_So_Module

and this is the problem, even with that i can access the Fs_SoService in SubOrderModule after calling it

Comment: Looking at your repo, I noticed you also mix casing when it comes to your imports. In some places its `fs_so.service` in others its `fs_So.service`. Make sure this is consistent, because of the way JS Realms and the `instanceof` operator function, they are _technically_ distinct imports

Comment: I would like to thank you for taking the time to look at the repo. What a stupid mistake I made; I was looking everywhere except here. Thanks a lot